# Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node. at remove From Favorites

Tags: html, css, node.js

The way I'm implementing is when i click the star-icon, it'll turn solid and will be added to Favorites and it'll be removed from Favorites when the star-icon is clicked again.

This is the error I get:
***Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node. at remove From Favorites.***

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    const openStudyResource = document.getElementById("openStudyResource")
    const favorites = document.getElementById("favorites")
    const studyResourceContainer = document.getElementById("studyResourceContainer")
    const jsonBoxes = document.getElementById("resources")

    const selectedResource = new Set();

    openStudyResource.addEventListener("click", function(){
        studyResourceContainer.style.left = "60px";
    })

    function addToFavorites(resource){
        const clone = resource.cloneNode(true);
        favorites.appendChild(clone);
    }
    
    function removeFromFavorites(resource){
        favorites.removeChild(resource);
    }

    function toggleFavorites(starIcon, resource){
        console.log(favorites)
        const isFav = starIcon.dataset.favorites === "true";

        if(isFav){
            starIcon.src = "images/star-regular.png";
            starIcon.dataset.favorites = "false";
            removeFromFavorites(resource);
        }
        else{
            starIcon.src = "images/star-solid.png";
            starIcon.dataset.favorites = "true";
            addToFavorites(resource);
        }
    }

    function createResourceBox(resource){
        const resourceBox = document.createElement("div");
        resourceBox.id = "resource-box";

        const resourceURL = document.createElement("a");
        resourceURL.href = resource.url;
        resourceURL.target = "_blank";

        const resourceName = document.createElement("div");
        resourceName.classList.add("resource-name");
        resourceName.textContent = resource.name;

        resourceURL.appendChild(resourceName)

        const resourceDescription = document.createElement("div");
        resourceDescription.classList.add("resource-description");
        resourceDescription.textContent = resource.description;

        const starIcon = document.createElement("img");
        starIcon.src = "images/star-regular.png";
        starIcon.alt = "favorites_Icon";
        starIcon.classList.add("star-icon");
        starIcon.dataset.favorites = "false";

        resourceBox.appendChild(starIcon)
        resourceBox.appendChild(resourceURL);
        resourceBox.appendChild(resourceDescription);

        starIcon.addEventListener("click", function(){
            toggleFavorites(starIcon, resourceBox);
        })

        return resourceBox;
    }
    
    fetch("/data/studyresource.json")
        .then(function(response){
            return response.json();
        })
        .then(function(jsonData){
            jsonData.sort(function(a,b){
                return a.name.localeCompare(b.name);
            });

            jsonData.forEach(function(resource){
                const box = createResourceBox(resource);
                box.classList.add("custom-box");
                jsonBoxes.appendChild(box);
            });
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.error("Error fetching study resource data:", error);
        });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do `resource.cloneNode(true)`, you create new Nodes, which are no longer related (reference-wise) to `resource`, even though their content appears the same (they are [cloned](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode)...).

Hence the error message when you attempt to remove the original `resource` from where you actually put its clone instead (`favorites.appendChild(clone)` but `favorites.removeChild(resource)`).

---

A simple solution could simply be to store a *reference* of the clone, e.g. alongside the `resource` directly, so that you can retrieve it to get the Node to be removed:

```js
function addToFavorites(resource){
  const clone = resource.cloneNode(true);
  favorites.appendChild(clone);
  // Keep a reference to clone alongside resource
  resource.cloneReference = clone;
}
    
function removeFromFavorites(resource){
  // Retrieve the clone Node
  const clone = resource.cloneReference;
  favorites.removeChild(clone);
}
```